# jquery Trigger delegate event for nth element onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my page i have 10 images all are have the same class   "select-option"

My html is

```
<div class="select-option swatch-wrapper selected" data-name="A Very Scary Monster" data-value="a-very-scary-monster">
<a href="#" style="width:120px;height:120px;" title="" class="swatch-anchor">
<img src="image ur1" alt="" class="" width="120" height="120"></a></div>
```

Similarly i have 10 images.

```
  function init_swatches() {

      $('.select-option').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
          ///////////// Some code here
        var $the_option = $(this).closest('div.select-option');

      });
}
```

I want to preselect the 3rd image. Thew selected image has the class 'selected', others are not. How do i trigger this for 3rd or 4th element on load. How to manually trigger this delegate event for nth element.

Here i want to trigger this click event

Answer (score 1):

First bind click event on anchor tag

```
$('.select-option').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
          ///////////// Some code here
        var $the_option = $(this).closest('div.select-option');

  });
```

then manuaaly trigger click event of 3rd element like given below

```
$('.select-option a').eq(2).click()
```

or

```
  $('.select-option a').eq(2).trigger("click")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery's trigger method

```
function init_swatches() {

  $('.select-option').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
      ///////////// Some code here
    var $the_option = $(this).closest('div.select-option');

  });
  $('.select-option a').eq(2).trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: I used this trigger event. But my click event is inside the function like 
function init_swatches() {
  $('.select-option').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) { ///// My code });
}
If so  the trigger is not working. Do you have any idea, how to call this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're wanting to trigger the click event, but rather use the click event to set the selected class. Something like this might be more suitable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).delegate(".select-option", "click", function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected") == false) {
            $(".select-option.selected").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
    });
    selectNthImage(3);
});

function selectNthImage(n) {
    $(".select-option.selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(".select-option:nth-child(" + n + ")").addClass("selected");
};
```

See a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KCZ3m/)